# Java reading past saved variables

Tags: java, file, io, save, stanford-nlp

I am taking questions from user input which is being scanned for information and i am saving the information and the original question.

What is the best way to save the question+information so that it can be recalled so that i am able to read X questions before the question just asked and get the information/variables on it?

```
An example:

[User]"what is 1+1?"
[Reply]"two"
save information: "what is 1+1","two"

[User]"how is the dog?"
[Reply]"fine"
save information:"how is the dog?",subject = "dog", condition = "fine"

getQuestion(1) -> "what is 1+1?"
getInformation(current) -> subject = "dog" condition = "fine"
```

Also what would be better to call the information for each question using, an int (question X), string (question) or other?

Code so far:

```
Map<String,String> variable = new HashMap<>();
    public QuestionInfo(String name,String variable) {
        this.variable.put(name, variable);
    }
    public String get(String name){
    if(variable.containsKey(name)) {
        return variable.get(name);
    } else {
        return "";
    }
    }
```

I though about using:

```
  Map<String,QuestionInfo> Questions = new HashMap<>();
```

first but then if i wanted to call i cant use an int
so instead:

```
Map<Integer,QuestionInfo> Questions = new HashMap<>();
```

then i can add the question as the first piece of information.

Comment: Your concern is about what structure to use ? or where to store them in a given application type ?

Comment: Yes I want to hear other peoples idea's of stucture to see if they sound any better than mine and I'm not sure whether to save as a single .txt or individual ones

Comment: I'm assuming you considered `Map<String,QuestionInfo>` for the ability to look up info by the question string. If that's useful, you could create both a `Map<String,QuestionInfo>` and a `List<QuestionInfo>` and when you create a new `QuestionInfo` instance, add it to both the map and the list. Then you will be able to look up questions both by int index and question string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to preserve the order of responses, you probably want to use a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Then you just need to decide what kind of list to make. Since you have two items that are closely related - the subject (a String) and condition - I would probably create a custom class:

```
import java.util.Map;
public class QuestionInfo {

    private String question;
    private Map<String, String> variables;

    public QuestionInfo(String question, Map<String, String> variables) {
        this.question = question;
        this.variables = variables;
    }

    public String question() {
        return question;
    }

    public Map<String, String> vars() {
        return variables;
    }
}
```

Then you would create your list to store these like this, for example:

```
List<QuestionInfo> questionList = new ArrayList<QuestionInfo>();
```

There are other ways to store these strings (for example, you could concatenate them with a delimiter, or use a String[2]).. but this will probably be the easiest to read and understand later, in my opinion.

Here's an approximation of what the user would enter, and how you would use the `questionList` + `QuestionInfo` to store the data:

[User] "how is the dog?"
[Reply] "fine"

```
Map<String, String> varMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
varMap.put("subject", "dog");
varMap.put("condition", "fine");
questionList.add(new QuestionInfo("how is the dog?", varMap));
```

Now you can access this info by using:

```
questionList.get(0).question() // returns "how is the dog?"
```

or

```
questionList.get(0).vars().get("condition") // returns "fine"
```

Note that this is glossing over the code to actually gather the user input.

There are other possibilities.
You could pass in a `String...` to the `QuestionInfo` constructor and parse the variables/create the map there, for example.
You also may want to store the entire response as a String separate from the variables.
You may also want to create an enum for the keys, if you have a consistent set of keys you'll be populating.

Comment: As there can be any amount of variables with any name to be saved, i can replace "String subject, String response" with "String... variables" however how can I then get that data using *unknownVariableName*() ?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I think you're trying to do too much at once. You would make a new `QuestionInfo` for each question and response pair. Using a list takes care of the fact that there are any number of questions and answers. I will add an example use to my original answer..

Comment: Yes I think I am, however i think you have misunderstood what i meant. The question and response are not pairs, the response is on of the pieces of information stored under the question. It should be able to call the name each piece of information individually for each question. Ill update the question with the code i have so far.

Comment: ahhh yes.. that makes sense now.. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think I would just create a "Question" class that would store the actual question and the information you want (subject, condition, etc.) and just store them in an array.

Some code adding your comment about having multiple answers (it's missing the setters, but I guess you get the idea):

```
public class Question {
    private String subject;
    private List<String> responses;

    public String getSubject(){
        return subject;
    }
    public String getResponse(int _index){
        if (_index <= response.size())
        {
            return response.get(_index);
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, however each question could have a different unknown number of variables which could cause problems. I would have to have an array which each element has a separate array. I believe it is possible though